# Simple CPP file failed to compile with Clang

Tags: clang, llvm

```
#include "clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h"  
#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"  
#include "clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h"  
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"  
#include "clang/Basic/FileManager.h"  
#include "clang/Basic/SourceManager.h"   
#include "clang/Basic/TargetOptions.h"  
#include "clang/Basic/TargetInfo.h"  
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"  
#include "clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h"  
#include "clang/Parse/ParseAST.h"  
#include "clang/Rewrite/Rewriter.h"  
#include "clang/Rewrite/Rewriters.h"  
#include "llvm/Support/Host.h"  

int main()  
{  
    return 0;  
}
```

I am compiling it as

```
clang++ -I/home/pc/llvm-3.3.src/tools/clang/include -I/home/pc/llvm-3.3-build/tools/clang/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -Wno-unused-parameter -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-uninitialized -Wnon-virtual-dtor   -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -fno-rtti   -c -o simple.o simple.cpp
```

I am getting error as   `'clang/Rewrite/Rewriter.h' file not found`

Comment: What makes you think rewriter.h exists?  Did you try using brackets (<>) instead if quotes?

Comment: Actually Rewriter.h doesn't exist at any location that are mentioned on command line with -I option. I did clean install, still problem persists. I do not know why Rewrite.h is not present in any of these locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About a year ago (before the release of llvm 3.2), ClangRewrite was split into 2 libraries: ClangRewriteCore and ClangRewriteFrontend.

This means that:

- **clang/Rewrite/Rewriter.h** is now **clang/Rewrite/Core/Rewriter.h**.
- **clang/Rewrite/Rewriters.h** is now **clang/Rewrite/Frontend/Rewriters.h**.
- **libclangRewrite.a** is now **libclangRewriteCore.a** and **libclangRewriteFrontend.a**.

You can see the change in the LLVM repository [here](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=163050).

Comment: Ohh..that is interesting and explains a lot to me. Thanks